# How can I go to a saved spot in my text?

Tags: python, python-2.x, raw-input

I'm trying to make 2 things: so first is, how can I go to a certain spot in the text? Like, if the person put in an invalid name, then I want it to go back to right before the question. Is there any way I can do that? And also, based on this code I wrote:

```
name = raw_input("What's your name?")
if name == "Sans":
    print "Yeah, Sure... Sans... 0//.//0"
    #dont judge me, it will be important later in the game. (sans from undertale)
if name == "Soph":
    print "Hey buddy. Lets try to pick our own names for now, okay?"
    #because that's my name lmao
```

How can I make it so that it runs that code for certain names, but after that code is run, no matter what, it continues with code that will run under all circumstances like an `if`/`else` statement? And one more thing, how do you put parentheses inside of parentheses so it prints the parentheses and doesn't read it as code?

And I *just* started learning python maybe a month ago, so don't judge me because of the simplicity of the game. I'd also like to know what version of python that is and how to get that version of `pygame`, since I can't find it!

Comment: Do you mean that for certain names, like `"Sans"` and `"Soph"`, it will run a print statement like in your example. And for all names, `"Jack"`, `"Jane"`, `"Sans"`, `"Soph"`, it will run some other code, after checking if it is `"Sans"` or `"Soph"`?

Comment: And could you clarify this sentence 'Id also like to know what version of python that is and how to get that version of pygame, since i cant find it!'

Comment: yeah. so the code for "sans" or "soph" will print something, and then after it prints that, it goes on and prints whatever code is next. if its neither of those names, than it skips that, and continues to the same code that runs no matter what.

Comment: like, is it python 2.7, or 3.4, or a different one? and what version of pygame would that be.

Comment: You can just put the code that will always run after your Sans/Soph checks.

Comment: And what are you referring to about which python? Are you asking which python you should be using? If you intend on using pygame, there is a list of compatible python versions on their [wiki page](http://pygame.org/wiki/PythonVersions).

Comment: Also if you find it difficult to describe what you're trying to accomplish, you should include some kind of inputs and expected outputs to your code. You should try to always include these in your question if you're program isn't doing what you'd like.

Comment: I mean, i dont know what version of python im using. i think its 2.7 but im not sure.

Comment: You can run this line `import sys; print(sys.version_info)` to check your version, using the sys module.

Comment: Just load the python interpreter - it prints the version number when it starts up.  Or you could start IDLE - the version # prints on the first line.

Comment: Thanks. Also, is there also a way to make it instead of running both the text that runs with sans/soph, and the regular, if you enter sans/soph, it runs that text and it’s done. If it’s not sans/soph, than I runs a different tact and stops. Is it an if else statement?

Comment: @Sophie Yes this is an if-else statement, you would want something like `if name == "Sans": ... elif name == "Soph": ... else: ...`